# Make a random of a dataset with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to extract 150 lines in random from a dataset of 500 lines. So I would do it at random.

**My data**

```
 object,color,label
 puppy,white,animal
 mango,orange,fruit
 pants,black,clothing
```

**My script**

```
 import pandas
 import pandas as pd

 df = pd.read_csv ('data.csv', sep = ',')
 data_random = df.sample (150)

 print (data_random)
```

But the result is very strange, I do not have the complete line...

```
     object ... label
 277 grape  ... fruit
 116 bear   ... animal
 495 ...    ... ...
```

Is it possible to have the full line?

Comment: How working `pd.options.display.max_columns = 20` ?

Comment: `pandas.DataFrame.sample` only samples according to rows (unless specified otherwise, but you didn't), so it must be a display problem. Try and check `data_random.shape` it should have the same number of columns as `df`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#better-pretty-printing-of-dataframes-in-a-terminal) for pandas 0.23.0:

> Previously, the default value for the maximum number of columns was **pd.options.display.max_columns=20**. This meant that relatively wide data frames would not fit within the terminal width, and pandas would introduce line breaks to display these 20 columns.
>
> If Python runs in a terminal, the maximum number of columns is now determined automatically so that the printed data frame fits within the current terminal width (pd.options.display.max_columns=0) (GH17023). If Python runs as a Jupyter kernel (such as the Jupyter QtConsole or a Jupyter notebook, as well as in many IDEs), this value cannot be inferred automatically and is thus set to 20 as in previous versions. In a terminal, this results in a much nicer output.

---

> Note that if you don’t like the new default, you can always set this option yourself. To revert to the old setting, you can run this line:

```
pd.options.display.max_columns = 20
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, check the Pandas options:

`pd.options.display.max_columns = 20`

Otherwise, check the setting of your Editor,  try it at Jupyter Notebook